# Change the menu caption

Tags: c#, winforms

I am invoking a `form` for user login from a menu item click using `Form.Show();`
Just wanted to change the `caption` of the menu, based on the login result. I know this is too basic, but I am not sure how to do it.

This is the code, which I have tried.

```
private void ChangeLogin_Click(Office.CommandBarButton cmdBarbutton, ref bool cancel)
{
    Login openLogin = new Login();
    openLogin.Show();
    if (openLogin.LoginValid)
    {
        cmdBarbutton.Caption = "Success";
    }
    else
    {
        cmdBarbutton.Caption = "Failure";
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a wpf project

Comment: This is not a WPF application, it is an Office application!

Comment: Why do you have a parameter of type Office.CommandBarButton? Is it an Office Addin?

Comment: Yes, Its an outlook addin.

Comment: @seb Please do not sign your questions. Also, no need to add thanks. It is just considered noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using WPF MenuItems:

```
menuItem.Header = openLogin.LoginValid ? "Success" : "Failure";
```

Also make sure to use `ShowDialog` instead of `Show` to block until the form is closed:

When using Office CommandBarButtons:

```
private void ChangeLogin_Click(Office.CommandBarButton cmdBarbutton, ref bool cancel)
{
    Login openLogin = new Login();
    openLogin.ShowDialog();
    cmdBarbutton.Caption = openLogin.LoginValid ? "Success" : "Failure";
}
```

Comment: I have tried it, Can you show me  based on the cod (I have updated my question)

Comment: @SebastianXavier - I added to my answer. Please make sure you are using `ShowDialog` instead of `Show`

Comment: It got worked. I didn't think in the proper way. Long time, since I did something like this.

Comment: So it was the ShowDialog?

Comment: BTW: Changing the Button captions is not very intuitive. A better UI practice is to enable/disable buttons and to show status in a status bar, not in a button unless it is a checkbox or combobox

Comment: First, I was using show(), Now just wanted to change it to showDialog().